# How to color arc in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsItem` which is made of `Line`, `Arc's` and `Circle`.  I have drawn a digital gate `XNOR` using arcs and lines and circles and colored it with blue color.
So when I initially load it looks like this:

[image]

But when I click somewhere else, arc's color gets disappeared. And it looks like this:

[image]

I have colored it like this:

myPoly.h

```
class myPoly: public QGraphicsPathItem 
  {
     public:
     explicit myPoly(BGType *boostGraph);
     explicit myPoly();
     myPoly(QPainterPath p) : QGraphicsPathItem(p) {}
     void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    void DrawPolyline(QPolygonF);
  }
```

myPoly.cpp

```
  void myPoly::DrawPolyline(QPolygonF polygon)
 {
    this->_polygon = polygon;
    QPainterPath pPath;
    pPath.addPolygon(polygon);
    this->setPen(QPen(QColor("gray"), 1));
    this->setPath(pPath);
 }         
   
     void myPoly::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                             QWidget *widget)
   {
       auto copied_option = *option;
       copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
      std::cout<<"Paint called "<<std::endl;
      QGraphicsPathItem::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
   }
```

myArc.h

```
class myArc: public QGraphicsPathItem
 {
   public:
      myArc(QPainterPath p) : QGraphicsPathItem(p) {}
      explicit myArc();
      void DrawArc();
 };
```

myArc.cpp

```
myArc::myArc()
{}
void myArc::DrawArc()
{
    QPen mPen;
    mPen.setWidth(1);
    mPen.setBrush(Qt::blue);
    this->setPen(mPen);
}
```

mySymbol.cpp

```
void mySymbol :: DrawSymbol() 
  {
       //Drawing Arc
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < iter->second._allArcs.size(); i++) 
         {       
            // getting 6 co-ordinates for Arc
            
            QPointF from(first, second);
            QPointF to(third, fourth);
            QPointF center(fifth, sixth);
            
            QLineF lineFrom{center, from};
            QLineF lineTo{center, to};
            qreal radius = lineFrom.length();
            QRectF bounding{center - QPointF{radius, radius},
                            center + QPointF{radius, radius}};
            
            QRectF bounding1(bounding.x() + x, bounding.y() + y, bounding.width(),bounding.height());
            
      // Use QLineF to calculate angles wrt horizontal axis.
            qreal startAngle = lineFrom.angle();
            qreal sweep = lineFrom.angleTo(lineTo);
            
            QPainterPath path;
            path.moveTo(from.x(), from.y());
            
            path.arcTo(bounding1, startAngle, sweep);
            myArc* arc = new myArc(path);
            
            arc->DrawArc();
            scene->addItem(static_cast<QGraphicsPathItem*>(arc));
      }   
                


 class myLine: public QGraphicsLineItem
{
  public:
    myLine();
    myLine(int x1,int y1,int x2 ,int y2,QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsLineItem(x1,y1,x2,y2,parent)
    {}
    void DrawLine();
};         

// Drawing line 
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < iter->second._allLines.size(); i++) 
{
  // getting 4 co-ordinates of lines.
  myLine* line = new myLine(first,second,third,fourth);
  line->DrawLine();
  scene->addItem(static_cast<QGraphicsLineItem*>(line));
 }
  
void myLine::DrawLine()
{
    this->setPen(QPen(QColor("blue"), 1));
}
```

Why this is happening ? And how to avoid it ?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the rest of your code. And tag only Qt5 OR Qt4.

Comment: @Botje  I have updated the code. Please look into it.

Comment: All of that looks perfectly normal. Are you doing something weird in the scene itself?

Comment: @Botje No. I am just clicking outside XNOR gate and only arc's color gets disappeared.

Comment: Can you produce a [mre]? Otherwise it is basically guesswork.

Comment: @Botje  Sorry but I have given all the code.  Not understanding why only arc's color is getting disappeared. Why not circle or lines color ?

Comment: This is not "all the code". This is not something I can compile and try for myself and debug to help you. This is literally a snippet that does nothing wrong. So either your computer is haunted, you ran into a Qt bug that nobody on the planet has ever encountered, or the error is in the rest of your code. Which of the three is the most likely?

Comment: @Botje  Yes, you are right. This is not the all code but I am avoiding to put all the code as it leads to not to read big question mentality.  And it is not my local machine code so has a restriction. Hope you will understand. But Now I have tried to put all the necessary code.

Comment: @Botje  I have found 1 lead like  If I click on symbols arc, paint method of `myPoly` class gets called. `myPoly` and `myArc` both are different classes but they have inherited from `QGraphicsPathItem`.  `myPoly` class is to draw `polylines` ( wires of symbols ). `myArc` , `myLine`  and `myEllipse` ( not mentioned here ) are for `arc`, `lines` and `circle` respectively.

Comment: Try overriding the `paint` method of your arc as well and put a breakpoint there. See what calls it after the initial paint, and check if the `pen` has changed in the meantime.

Comment: @Botje  I have checked , after initial paint call, if I click on `arc` or click on somewhere else ( not on symbol )  both paint method gets called.  But not understanding how to check `pen` has changed in the meantime.

Comment: @Botje  1 more doubt : When `paint` gets called ?  If I click on that object, then that objects `paint` gets called or If I click somewhere else in scene ( not on any object but on blank space ) then also `paint` gets called  ?   In my case, if I click on blank space  then also both `paint` is getting called.

Comment: @Botje 1 more observation, before adding symbol, I had polylines ( wires ).  Their original color was `gray` .  I wanted to select the wires, so through flags ( `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);` ) and `paint` method I did that.  So when I used to select wires it gets darken in color ( means selected ) and if I click somewher else, then that selection used to disappear and becomes original color gray. Now also same is happening.  Click on somewhere else, arc is becoming gray.

Comment: None of that is present in your code paste. How did you expect me to guess that? As for "when paint gets called" : debugger and breakpoint in paint.

Comment: @Botje I checked, 1st polylines `paint` gets called and then arc's `paint` gets called.  Both `paint` are different. They are different for different class.  Then how is this happeneing ?

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint , look at the call stack. Probably just in response to clicking the scene?